# cc linker gives no error, but the resulting library is not linked to libgstvideo-1.0

Tags: linker, gstreamer, cc

I'm using cmake to generate a gstreamer library. In the end cmake uses the following command for linking:

```
/usr/bin/cc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libmacq-gstmelpi.so -o libmacq-gstmelpi.so <OBJECT_FILES> -lmacq-melpi -lmacq-icar-tools -lmacq-gstmecimeta -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstvideo-1.0
```

Note the **-lgstvideo-1.0** flag at the end. The command runs fine, no error is produced, and the resulting library is created just fine. However when I use the library, I get **undefined symbol** error. So I use `ldd` to check; and amongst all the output of ldd; **libgstvideo-1.0.so** is **not** to be found.

This problem occurs on Ubuntu 14.04 on a armhf architecture. The problem does not occur on opensuse 13.1 (i586) nor on opensuse 13.1 (armv7hl), since in that case `ldd libmacq-gstmelpi.so | grep gstvideo` gives:

```
libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 (0xb715f000)
```

**EDIT :**

I have another library, very similar where a very similar command works just fine; the resulting library is correctly linked to libgstvideo-1.0.so

```
/usr/bin/cc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libmacq-gstplugins.so -o libmacq-gstplugins.so <OBJECT_FILES> -lmacq-icar-tools -lmacq-gstmecimeta -lgstapp-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstvideo-1.0
```

Some remarks on what I have checked and tried:

- /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstvideo-1.0.so exists. (the other libraries in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ are found without problem, libmacq-gstmelpi.so is linked to /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 without problem)
- I tried changing the order, and putting the **-lgstvideo-1.0** flag before all other **-l** flags; no succes.
- replacing `cc` with `c++` or `gcc`; the commands work, but output is the same
- removing **-lgstvideo-1.0** on a system where the build worked. The resulting library builds (links) without error; yet upon execution I have the same **undefined symbol** error as on Ubuntu. This proves that the missing symbol is in libgstvideo-1.0.so, and that I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you actually using symbols from that particular library or do you just want to link to it to avoid linking it in the application that uses the library later on?

It could be a default compiler behavior that it skips linking of libraries when no symbol from these are actually used.

Try `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to your flags. In this case the library should get linked - not checking whether its symbols are actually used or not.

EDIT:
After chatting it turned out that the actual desired symbols are in gstbase-1.0 and not gstvideo-1.0. Since gstvideo-1.0 pulls in gstbase-1.0 as a dependency this worked but would cause problem as the linker may remove this dependency since no symbols from this particular library are being used. Linking directly to gstbase-1.0 seemed to solve all issues.

Comment: Yes I do need some symbols; strangely enough when I remove `-lgstvideo-1.` from the linking command line; my library is produced without error. Again upon execution; undefined symbol...

Comment: I retried with your flag "--no-as-needed", and now it did get linked... this is so strange!

Comment: Your linker flag solves the problem allright; but it is very strange that I need to do this...

Comment: It is not too strange. Compilers try to help you in all possible ways. So if you accidently add a library that is not needed at all it may try to get rid of it entirely to not cause unneeded dependencies.

Comment: I understand that, but what is strange is that I do need that library, and that the linker doesn't detect that!

Comment: You said you can drop this library altogether and your library is still linking. I assume this: Your library does not use gst-video-1.0 at all - but your application does. What you should do is remove gst-video-1.0 from your library but instead link your application to this library. gst-video-1.0 is completely optional to the base gstreamer-1.0 library.

Comment: No there is a real underlying problem. In the code of my library I **do** use the function `gst_queue_array_pop_head`. If not linked to gstvideo-1.0 I get undefined symbol errors on this function...

Comment: Well the first comment says dropping the video part the library builds. So all symbols were linked - none is missing. gst_queue_array_pop_head seems to be in gstreamer/base if the documentation can be trusted. It sounds to me there is something else in your app that causing this dependency.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105356/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-florian-zwoch).